# Removing all printer stuff

Tags: printing, driver, macos

I don't use any printers now, but I have in the past.
Systems Preferences / Printers & Scanners shows "No printers are available".
However, /Library/Printers still contains over 200Mb of stuff.

How can I clean the contents of /Library/Printers and any other folders that contain printer stuff?

I suppose /Library/Printers protected by SIP and so `sudo rm` will not work, nor is recommended.

I'm running El Captain 10.11.6 (15G21013).

Comment: Did you try to `rm` the content of `/Library/Printers`?

Comment: @nohillside, I did not, lest something breaks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple says it is safe to remove the content of /Library/Printers: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203343#remove.

I did that after resetting the printing system, just to be sure.