# How to remove old epson software from iMac?

Tags: macos, imac

My iMac has been running slow and hanging.  I looked and found that a lot of old EPSON printer software is still running and installed. I found an `uninstall` executable in finder:

[image]

But when I try to open that I get this error:

[image]

So I tried looking at that file via `terminal` and I found that is actually a directory and the actuall executable is here:

```
MyiMac:/ root# /Applications/Epson\ Software/Uninstaller.app/Contents/MacOS/Uninstaller
```

and when I execute that executable this window eventually pops up and hangs:

[image]

How can remove this epson garbage off my system?

Update: I have followed the instructions described here: https://epson.com/Support/wa00350

and the EPSON folder has been removed from the `/Library/Printers`:

[image]

Yet there is still EPSON software running on my system:

[image]

And I can still see EPSON applications in launchpad:

[image]

Note I did have trouble rebooting my iMac and had to pull the power plug out because the system hung during boot up.  Fortunately, the second boot attempt was successful.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://epson.com/Support/wa00350

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/339269/22769

Comment: @DaniilManokhin  I did see that web page.  But I must be having a brain cramp because when it gets to step 4, Open the Hard Drive, I have no clue what then mean by "Open the Hard Drive".

Comment: Ok they mean to use finder and click on the "Macintoch HD" and then "Library" folder icon then on the "Printers" folder icon.

Comment: @RedCricket Try using uninstalled again

Comment: I ran the uninstaller again ... this time it actually completed "Reading software information" and presented me with software to uninstall, but when I click uninstall I got an error message say that the software was in use.  So I just moved the `/Applications/EPSON` folder to the trash and shutdown and booted.  Now the epson software is gone! Hurray!

Comment: @RedCricket yay! Do you want be to compile all the info into an answer to help other users?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked (for other users):

Follow the instructions [here:](https://epson.com/Support/wa00350)

> 1. From the Apple menu, select System  Preferences.
> 2. Click Print & Fax.
> 3. Highlight any Epson printers and click the ￼ button to remove them from the Printers list, then click OK.
> 4. Open the hard drive
> 5. Select Library > Printers.
> 6. Select the folder labeled EPSON and drag it to the trash.
>
> Note: This will remove all installed Epson printer drivers. You’ll
>   need to reinstall any printer drivers that you still need.

If the software is still on your computer then try using the uninstaller.

This should completely remove all the software.